# broncin' buck -- what does that mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

From the song [American Pie](https://play.google.com/music/preview/Tc7k3krcpmbobgxvt2m5mmlzcaq?lyrics=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=lyrics&pcampaignid=kp-lyrics) by [Don McLean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_McLean):

> I was a lonely teenage **broncin' buck**
>   With a pink carnation and a pickup truck
>   But I knew I was out of luck
>   The day the music died
>   I started singin'

Could you please tell me what *broncin' buck* means?

Comment: ["Teenage broncin' buck"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=teenage%20broncin%27%20buck) googles easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the link in my comment, the "broncin' buck" expression originates from ["bucking bronco"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bucking+bronco), a wild horse that is vicious and difficult or impossible to break in, where *"bronco"* means an unbroken or imperfectly broken mustang and *to buck* means to resist.

As a noun, ["buck"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/buck) may also mean a male deer, antelope, etc., a stallion included.

Comment: Don McLean might have reversed "bucking" and "bronc" to rhyme with "truck"

Comment: +1. For extra credit, @Rompey: explain the pink carnation :)

Comment: @TRomano - You don't mean symbolic flower language, do you? May it be just an imaginary flower of choice as the sign of leaving home for good? Or should I post a question about it since it wasn't asked about by the PO?

Comment: A question about the significance of the flower would  be considered off-topic, as "lit-crit".

Comment: @TRomano fortunately, there's now a site for that... [literature.se] :D

Comment: @Catija, but have they decided whether lyrics are literature or not yet? (Or are they just going to accept the authority of the Nobel committee?)

Comment: @ThePhoton [Last I saw](http://meta.literature.stackexchange.com/questions/67/are-songs-and-poems-on-topic), provided the question is about the lyrics, not the music, questions about songs are on topic.